# NoSQL/SQL Databases which return results by relevance

Tags: sql, database, search, nosql

I am on the lookout for any NoSQL/SQL database that provides functionality similar to Lucene/Solr erc. where the results are ordered by **relevance** to a query. e.g. NumVal1 between 1 and 3, NumVal2 between 4 and 5 and so on...

I learned [MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696627/mongodb-query-results-ordering-numeric-range-query) doesn't do this, and AFAIK neither does Couch.

Example of my need:

```
Doc1: 
 - NumField 1 : 9.9
 - NumField 2: 8.2

Doc2:
 - NumField 1 : 5.9
 - NumField 2: 8.9


**Query**
 - NumField 1: Between 7 & 10
 - NumField 2: Between 8 & 10
```

I would want Doc1 to show up before Doc2.

Any suggestions? I am very familiar with Lucene/Solr, but looking for an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elastic Search (another way to say Lucene) would be my go-to component for this use case.